# Deployment Target for iOS Apps

Tags: ios, xcode

As of 2019, I mean latest. What is the minimum deployment target I should set in Xcode? I set it as 12.1, hence I could not run on my I-Phone which is the iOS version 11.2. Help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "should" for your minimum deployment target. It's a question of what audience you are intending to release to. Just specify the earliest system on which your app is to run. If you want it to run on iOS 11.2, specify 11.2 (or earlier).